# How to add text and href on image on material_side_nav using shinymaterial package

Tags: r, shiny, materialize

I use `shinymaterial` package for my shiny app. I run into a problem which I try to modify the image on the top of `material_side_nav`, I want to add text and href on that image, but I couldn't figure out which way.

I use HTML to add the image with href which I like it, but then the image position is not on the top of `material_side_nav`, I edit css `padding: 0` or `top: 0`, it still doesn't work.

This is a method using `image_source`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

ui <- material_page(

  title = "Shinymaterial Testing",
  nav_bar_fixed = TRUE,
  include_fonts = T,
  nav_bar_color = "teal lighten-1",

  material_side_nav(
    image_source = "logo.jpg",
    background_color = "blue lighten-4",
    shiny::tags$h4("Side-Nav Content")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is the method I use HTML

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

ui <- material_page(

  title = "Shinymaterial Testing",
  nav_bar_fixed = TRUE,
  include_fonts = T,
  nav_bar_color = "teal lighten-1",

  material_side_nav(
    #image_source = "logo.jpg"

    HTML('
      <ul id="slide-out"  class="sidenav">
      <li><div style="height:160px" class="userView">
      <div style="height:160px" class="background">
        <img style="height:160px;width:300px;" src="logo.jpg">
        </div>
        <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="xmas.png"></a>
        <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
        <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
      </div></li></ul>

      ')
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Using `image_source`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKiZH.jpg)

[Using HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DzZl.jpg)

And this is HTML

```
> material_side_nav(
+   image_source = "logo.jpg",
+   background_color = "blue lighten-4",
+   shiny::tags$h4("Side-Nav Content")
+ )
<style type="text/css"></style>
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav blue lighten-4">
  <li>
    <div style="height:160px" class="userView">
      <div class="background">
        <img style="height:160px;width:300px" src="logo.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <h4>Side-Nav Content</h4>
</ul>
<script>   $(document).ready(function () {

       $('.nav-wrapper').prepend('<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>');
       $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
   })</script>
>
```

Any suggest? Thank you.